# Could Husk escape Toad's slime attack?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

If Paige Guthrie (Husk) was slimed by Toad, would she be able to shed it off or would she need to be saved? I would think so, but I am just looking for another point of view.

Comment: Okay, at this point I think you should ask one question asking about the effectiveness of Toad's slime, rather than coming up with endless situations involving him and random characters.

Comment: Fine. Which female X-Men would be affected by Toad's slime?

Comment: Um... are you doing research for some X-Men slash fiction?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite slash-fiction is same-sex. Toad + X-Women would not fall under that category (unless there have been some massive changes to Toad in the past year).

Comment: @RyanOtterman we are not trying to be dicks, we're trying to be helpful. The questions you are asking are highly unlikely to attract anyone willing to give an answer, because they are so seemingly trivial and arbitrary. If there is some more interesting purpose underlying this series of "Toad vs the wimminz" questions, you should just ask that, as you're far more likely to attract good answers.

Comment: @phantom42: I think some Toads *can* change sex, so maybe it’s within the realms of possibility. I didn’t realise that was the definition of slash fiction.

Comment: Working on a project called X-Men: Humanity's Defenders and am having trouble coming up with certain characters. So far it involves Toad, Blob, Juggernaut, Magneto, Blink, Mystique, Amp, Cyclops, and Wolverine. Please respond for further info.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I'm fairly confident that Husk could escape Toad's slime, for two reasons:

1. When she sheds her skin, it physically comes off, like a snake. Anything stuck to the outside of her skin would likely come with it. Even superficial injuries to her skin disappear when she sheds. The only way I can see this not working is if the adhesive slime somehow prevented her from removing the skin from her mount, in which case:
2. Beneath her skin she can trans-morph into other substances, *including liquids*. Worst case, she could morph into water and simply let herself flow away from the slime before reverting to her original form.

Answer (score 0):

Without a doubt, yes. Paige Guthrie (Husk's) mutation deals with, and I'm quoting Marvel Comics Database here: Transitional Omni-morph. It goes on to state the following: Husk has the mutant ability to shed her outer layer of skin and reveal a new state or shape underneath. Her power can cause random changes if she activates it without thinking, but by concentrating on specific chemical or elemental formulas, she can control the nature of her transformation (end quote). Now, over the years, Paige has shown the ability to transform into wood, rubber, glass, granite, metal, diamond, and even Adamantium, which, apart from Uru and vibranium, is one of the most rare and deadly metals in the Marvel Universe. Add to the fact that most of these forms have given Paige increased stamina, strength, durability, flame-protection, and even amphibious talents, not only would Paige be freeing herself, she would be in a much more dangerous form than before the sliming. Take into account that she has managed to 'husk' a form that can damage Kitty Pryde while she is phasing and a form that can melt Colossus' organic steel skin, and Toad is done for.